# Create a loop in order to generate colnames in a large list

Tags: r, loops

I would like to create a loop in order to change the column names as shown:

```r
a <- c("day", "month", "year", "flow")
```

I've got a large list of 6937 elements that I managed to import into R:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(readtext)



txt_files_ls <- paste("C:/Users/obarresi/Desktop/doc osvaldo/ana_data_acquisition/data_flow-ANA/All", 
                      list.files(path = "C:/Users/obarresi/Desktop/doc osvaldo/ana_data_acquisition/data_flow-ANA/All",
                                 pattern = "*.txt"), sep = "/")

txt_files_df_list <- vector("list", length(txt_files_ls))

txt_files_df_list <- lapply(txt_files_ls, 
                            function(x){data.frame(read.table(file = x, header = F,
                                                              sep ="",colnames(x)))})
```

How to do this into all my df inside my list:

```r
txt_files_df_list[[1]] <- colnames(c("day", "month", "year", "flow"))
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach it like this:

```
txt_files_df_list %>%
  map(~ set_names(., c("day", "month", "year", "flow")))
```

Comment: Great! It worked perfectly when I assigned the code into a new object. Many thanks!

Comment: You can use %<>% instead of %>% in order to replace the object directly.